# Running cron as non-root or other cron alternatives that can be run as non-root?

Tags: kubernetes, cron

I have a requirement to convert my pod/containers within pod to run as non-root. This means the use of sudo, chown, mkdir, etc. can't be used and alternatives must be found.

One of the containers starts a cron process and is ran as root:

`root     22     7     0 10:30 ?      00:00:00 cron -n -s`

However, this isn't allowed and as such I am looking for alternatives to this. Trying to run this process as non-root doesn't seem to work - is anyone aware of alternatives to cron that can work in this context?

Comment: I see you have the kubernetes label. K8s has its own cron system: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly there are no alternatives for this.

To run your Cron as a non-root user, you would need to create a user in the Dockerfile and give it permissions to read/write/execute whatever it needs. Finally, select that user in the Dockerfile using `USER <my-user>`.

Finally, you could enforce security using [securityPolicies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-the-security-context-for-a-container) for that container.

On top of that, Kubernetes has a dedicated [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) ressource to run ... Cron Jobs ;)

CronJobs also allow you to use `securityPolicies`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a created a UID that this particular container will run as. 
I have done the following:
- Created an ARG for this new user: `ARG SGUSER=189692`

- Set the user (before my entrypoint): `USER $SGUSER`

- cron is usually started in my entrypoint script with `cron -n -s`, and then the entrypoint is called in the Dockerfile with `ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/catatonit", "--", "/bin/bash",  "/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]` - to get it working with your solution, what other steps would I need to carry out? Thanks for any help :)

Comment: No problem :) Good, so far the container has a non-root user that you should login as when the container starts ! Now run the container a first time (locally or using Kube) and see if you face any permission issues, for example if the program tries to write to a directory in which the user doesn't have write permissions, or anything that crashes the program. If so, fix them using chmod, chown etc... commands before the ```USER $SGUSER``` instruction. Do you have a sample of the program the cron will execute ? Or can you describe it ?